# Having trouble coverting a MongoDB query into a C++ query

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

I have this query

```
var startVal = Math.random();
db.coll.find({r: {$gt: startVal}}).sort({r: 1}).limit(1);
```

What's tripping me up is the sort. Can anyone help me convert this query into a C++ query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
QUERY("r" << BSON("$gt" << startVal ) ).sort("r" << 1)
```

or even more simple:

```
QUERY("r" << GT << startVal ).sort("r")
```

`limit` is expressed as part of the call to execute the query (3rd param)

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("DB.coll", QueryHere, 1);
```